# Any reasons at all *not* to use MySQL in this scenario

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation

I want to know if there is *any reasons at all* **not** to use MySQL in this scenario.

> 2 servers behind a virtual IP with MySQL master-master replication

Goal: redundancy, want this to run 24/7 servicing a [liferay cluster](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview)

I have plenty of reasons why to use this <sup>(**1**</sup> **I want your most pessimist thoughts**.

(1

We are using this already in an similar situation and are considering using something else for a new setup. We have access to s MSSQL cluster that are more than capable of handling the 24/7 demand.

Top reasons to use MySQL (as you see they are manly *"political"*)

- It's how we have done it in the past, so less surprises expected
- We<sup>(**2**</sup> will have more control over performance as we can add memory/cpu to the (virtual) db-servers ourselves when we want
- No need to migrate export data from MySQL to a new DB

(2

The MSSQL cluster is run by the "windows"-crew whilst I belong to the "*nix"-crew. So while the cooperation between us is good there is naturally a bit more fuss/delay when you have to ask someone else to do something rather than doing it yourself.

---

#### Update

Two days after this question was asked the decision what solution to use was made, so any answers<sup>(**3**</sup> that would have helped make that decision is now not needed (this time anyhow).

If anyone want to generalize this question ([as Jeff suggested](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/my-question-does-not-seem-to-go-anywhere-should-it-be-deleted/177#177)) please do.

(3

When this update was written there was only [one answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/any-reasons-at-all-not-to-use-mysql-in-this-scenario/1164#1164)

Comment: Perhaps add some detail about "liferay" e.g. what are the requirements of this system? Does it need to be truly 24/7/365? Does it have hard requirements for ACID? How much data, how many transactions per second? Would some of its features be better implemented as SPs? Etc etc.

Comment: @Gaius - I didn't add any more details than this because I *know* that MySQL is up to the task. It is fully supported and well tested. But I have been tasked with doing a pro and con list for MySQL. I want the cons.

Comment: In that case, I'd say it's not a technical decision really, it's an operational one. For example you mention the Windows crew is already set up for 24/7 support of SQL Server - how's your Unix crew set up for 24/7 support of MySQL, load balancing, SAN (if you're using it), tape backup and restore etc, do you have enough people with both the skills and the willingness to carry a pager, etc.

Comment: @Gaius - Thanks for your input. Backup, having people on call is and other issues is identical for all it-sub-departments within our organization (a university) so both solutions would use the same backup solutions and the same SAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the cons that I see, this being a somewhat subjective question:

### There are political reasons for and against this setup.

I don't know if I can be any more clear than that.

I would think this would be a huge benefit, so I would use this as my main selling point, because otherwise I don't see why not use the existing infrastructure to do what you need:

No need to migrate export data from MySQL to a new DB

Note that that's really going to turn into a con for you pretty quickly, cos everyone will say "just put a stub in that converts the MySQL requests into MSSQL" and that's going to be the negative all over again.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm slightly in favour of using MSSQL. **Firstly** it's two servers less for me to worry about. **Secondly** it's cheaper (those two are related actually). Both solutions come with an equivalent price tag for CPU/RAM/Disk but for the MySQL-solutions the man-hours(1) for administrating it would be the main cost, and that cost is zero for the cluster. **(1)** We (the organization) have a fixed tariff of ** x man-hours/server per month **

Comment: A bit late but we ended up sticking with MySQL

Comment: because of cost?

Comment: No it came down to migration issues. The suppliers claim that migrating to mssql was easy (or indeed possible) was *higly* exaggerated.